# Do Unions prevent the use of register variables

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-optimization, cpu-registers, unions

In [Agner Fog's Optimizing Software in C++ book](https://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf) he has the following advice (Page 94)

[image: union is not optimal because it prevents the use of register variables]

How does a union prevent the register variables being used? Running some toy examples in compiler explorer (`o3`) did not reveal such limitation.

Comment: The fact that `a` and `b` are many kilobytes in size would likely prevent them from being in registers, whether or not they are in a union together.

Comment: Note that [`register` has been removed from the language as of C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/register).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the highlighted sentence says "simple variables" so the assumption is that it's not kilobytes of data

Comment: Though that indeed may be the case on compilers that Agner knows of, we can't prove that statement (it would be like [proving a negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proving_a_negative)).  There is nothing about unions alone that prevents using register for their storage; a union of size int could easily live in a register.

Comment: @ErikEidt thanks, that's what I wanted to know - if you put that as an answer, I can then go ahead and accept it

Comment: Unclear whether Agner Fog is talking about the obsolete `register` keyword, or if he's talking about compilers keeping variables in registers.  Been a while since I read his C++ guide; I usually just check things in his microarchitecture guide, and look at actual compiler output for any specific thing I'm concerned about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be an ABI specific answer, but if you had a `union` vs an `int`... and is passed to a function the `union` has to be pushed on the stack where an `int` could be passed in a register, same goes for pointers, float types, etc... but that applies to `structs`/`class instances`, so it doesn't seem like a very great concern to me... `unions` are codesmell out side of embedded programming, because if you are using them for something like parsing, that parser ( eg. overlayed `char[]` to a `struct` ) is only guaranteed to work if it works, struct packing is up to the compiler and even with hints it can do what it wants, also obviously a change in endianness would break every multibyte member.

In this example if you used the enum as a function param it would have to go on the stack, but a pointer to either member could be passed in a register, but ... a pointer to the enum could go in a register anyway... they just don't decay to pointers like arrays do though.

Comment: As an example, x86-64 System V passes a `union{ int i; float f; }` in an integer register (https://godbolt.org/z/cPMenrhWf), the same as it would an `int`.  So a function wanting to use it as a `float` needs an extra `movd xmm0, edi`.  Some calling conventions make all aggregates special, and pass them not in registers.

Answer (score 1):

The practical answer is: it doesn't matter. Unions are only worth it when the memory saved is substantial (the example in the question only saves a few kB, which probably matters only on embedded systems). But the register comment would only matter for unions small enough that their members fit in registers. Even for embedded systems, that's several orders of magnitude difference.

Bottom line: avoid unions, until profiling shows a direct memory pressure problem, and then see if you can solve if with derived classes instead, or `std::variant`. `union` is a C solution.

Comment: I understand. It's always down to profiling. However, that does not help with discussions amongst colleagues when these kinds of questions come up. Especially in gamedev, where we are regularly hit by death by a thousand cuts (we can profile all we want, but the 'cuts' are too spread out and information like the one I asked in the question can be invaluable). We need to pre-emptively avoid cache misses as much as we can.

All that to say, in my case at least it _does_ matter.

Comment: This answer seems to accept the claim that not being a "register variable" is meaningful.  Yeah it can't be a `register union foo  myvar`, but optimizing compilers don't need the `register` keyword to keep data in registers while they're working on it.  That's why C++17 removed it from the language.  https://godbolt.org/z/4YTMbdhzM shows GCC happily keeping a `union foo{int i; float f;};` in a loop that only uses the int member, optimizing it just like if I'd loaded into an `int` temporary.  (@Samaursa). Calling conventions might handle small aggregates differently than a single scalar, though

Comment: @PeterCordes: Where do I use the phrase "register variable" or something similar? Your "local variable with union type" is atypical; it doesn't really save memory. My point basically is that the saving is worth it when you have a million of them, and then you can't put all of them in registers anyway.

Comment: The part of your answer that directly deals with the question is the sentence *But the register comment would only matter for unions small enough that their members fit in registers.*"  Which fails to answer / debunk the key point of the question, and is phrased like it's accepting it as a downside.  If you have a million small unions, the one you're currently working with can be in a register while you are.  If you want to write a general answer about not recommending unions, that's ok, but I think it should at least try to answer the specific question in a 1 sentence summary.